# Realm's write transactions

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2, realm

I'm a but puzzled with Realm's write transactions. Must I do all modifications to objects within a write transaction, or can I just make a few modifications and later on write everything down to disk?

The first option seems a bit overkill and certainly tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

That's correct! Once an object has been added to a `Realm()` object, it can only be modified in a write transaction afterwards.

This is done to ensure thread-safety. When a `Realm()` has a write transaction opened on it, it blocks every other thread from trying to open a write transaction at the same time (making them wait until the transaction has been closed).

It certainly might seem a bit overkill, and we're certainly looking at ways to try and make it a bit more streamlined, but for now, we think this implementation pattern provides the safest way to ensure your data is properly saved to disk.